# Is return r always valid?

Tags: c++, function

It is hard to explain my question, so feel free to ask for clarification. I have a function let's say:

```
int m(int i,int j)
{
    int r;
}
```

At some point I set `r=(mi,j+1)` and in the end, I say return r, but is this valid? In other words, to determine the value of `m(int i,int j)` I need the value of`m(i,j+1)` or the value of`m(i-1,j)` etc.

In other words, I say return `r`, but r cannot be determined unless we find the value of `m(i,j+1)`, but this follows after `m(i,j)`. Is there any problem?

Edit: I will show you an example code to help you get what I mean:

```
int m(int i,int j)
{
   int r;
   if(x[N][j]==1 && y[N][j]==1)
   r=1
   else if(x[i][j]==1 && y[i][j]==-1)
   r=m(i,j-1)
   else 
   r=m(i+1,j)
   return r;
}
```

Comment: That's called "recursion". And yes, it's valid.

Comment: What language? Also, whrn you write `r=(i,j+1)`, do you mean `r=m(i,j+1)`?

Comment: cpp and yes:  r=m(i,j+1)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, when you use recurrsion, you call the values found before. But here the value of m(i,j) can only be found from the value of m(i,j+1), so it is not a recursion.

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis A function calling itself is always recursion. It would be easier to answer your question when you would present the full code of your recursive function `m()`.

Comment: I edited the initial post to give an example

Comment: Your example will not stop (or rather will run out of stack and fault). So, `return r` will never be reached.

Comment: Why??????????????

Comment: @HerrJoebob of course it can stop. Exactly when `x[N][j]==1 && y[N][j]==1`. And to answer OP question: It's recursion and it's valid. The only *real* problem I see is in the case where the above condition is never met, then it will not terminate.

Comment: @lopho They changed the example after my comment.